# Installing Router inside Electrical Closet and Hacking the Telephone Socket

Tags: electrical-panel, routers, internet, the-netherlands

I live in the Netherlands and I have a router which I would like to hide away in my closet. Currently, it gets internet from the telephone socket seen in the image below.

[image: a router, a black rectangular box, connected to a wall socket]
[image: the same wall socket, now unplugged, showing a socket for a four pronged plug]

I would like to place this router in my closet, near the electrical service panel, seen in the image below.

The closet includes an electrical socket, however, it does not have a socket for the internet/telephone connection. I assume that my internet/telephone cables do pass through the closet as it's the main entrance for outside connections (electricity, gas, water etc.). How can I find out which cables these are? What is a good way to *hack* these cables and make my own internet-socket there?

[image: a utility closet, with a black electrical panel containing the breakers, electrical conduit to its left and right, with some other wires and boxes of an unknown nature as well]

I understand that the information I have provided may not be enough to describe a detailed plan of what I should do. My question here aims to get information which can guide me in connecting the internet plug seen in the first image to whichever wires are the telephone connection in the last image.

Comment: I've deleted the original question, and removed the comments from this one.  In the future, try to include as much information as you can in your questions, including but not limited to the country you're doing the work in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For connecting the router to your phone line, you need to find the '[ISRA punt](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISRA)' (this is specific to the Netherlands). This is where the phone company line from outside connects to the phone wiring in your house. The cable up to the ISRA punt is owned by the phone company and you're not allowed to modify it. You are allowed to modify the wiring that comes out of the ISRA punt at the consumer end.

There have been several standard shapes for this over the years. In older houses the ISRA punt may not even be in the metering closet.

[This KPN page](https://www.kpn.com/faq/5218) helps you identify the ISRA punt:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Does your metering closet contain an ISRA punt?

Comment: I am not completely sure if I found the "ISRA" demarcation point. The grey rectangular box on the top left of image #3 has the acronym "PTT" (an old Dutch telecom company) on it. So I think that might be it. It has two large cables coming out at the top and at the bottom, and a smaller cable coming out of the side. I haven't opened it - should I?

Comment: Yes, there should be a cover you can open, with screw terminals for the user-side wiring.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the Netherlands, but in the U.S., phone wiring does not necessarily have a demarcation in the same place as the rest of the utilities. The main demarcation point would be on the outside of the house in its own enclosure. From there, it goes up through the wall, into the attic (or basement), and runs to each telephone jack. Newer construction may have a junction panel inside the house somewhere like a closet for easy access.

After looking at your picture, it's possible that there would be telephone wiring in one of the conduits in the picture. You would need to find a way to access the wiring in each one visually, of course.

Tracing the wiring in the attic or basement is the best way to know for sure.

Comment: +1 :) What is a good way to *trace* such wires? I can open up the socket seen in image#2 to expose the wires there, and probably I can expose some wires in the closet of image#3, but how can I figure out which is which?

Comment: Here (In Italy) the demarcation point is the 'first' telephone socket inside the house. So ask your provider what is the point. I suggest you to do an extension without altering the existing system but remember: phone cord can't run in 'mains voltage' conduit, but can use low-voltag ones (eg: TV conduits, doorphone, LAN)